# Loading local XML in IE

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

Im trying to read a local xml file without using active-x in IE based on code from [this site](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/04/easy-xml/)

```
var xml = document.createElement("xml");
xml.src = 'file.xml';
document.body.appendChild(xml);
var xmlDocument = xml.XMLDocument;
document.body.removeChild(xml);

console.log(xml.XMLDocument); //undefined
console.log(xml); //<xml XMLDocument="[object]">
```

What I need here is the `[object]` that contains my XML file. But I can't manage to fetch it (see above). Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: @Serge On my local file system

Comment: Is page itself loaded from a remote source?

Comment: @Serge No, it's located on my computers desktop

Comment: Could you try to comment out the document.body.removeChild(xml)?

Comment: This article is from april 2006. At this time the newest IE-version was IE6. Try the code with IE6 and will get [object] 2 times(of course you can't use console, there is no console in IE6)

Comment: @Dr.Molle Ok, but is there any way to extract the object to a varlable?

Comment: @Johan, [http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dont.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dont.asp) has an example how XML tag loads the XML source and how the content is referenced within `<table/>` tag `datasrc` attribute. Try something like that to see if you can see the content of your file rendered as table.

Comment: @alexi Thanks, but i wanted to get the object from javascript in this case. Noticed that the property didnt exist in IE9, thus causing a problem for me.

Comment: @Johan, I would doubt for its NON EXISTANCE. It is documented in MSDN, and has a note `Internet Explorer 5 and later`. This is for [XML tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535918(v=vs.85).aspx) and this is [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535155(v=vs.85).aspx). Just follow the links.

Comment: @alexi `('XMLDocument' in xml)` is false in ie9 only.

Comment: What about to simulate IE9 to be IE8? It is possible by including `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">` in `<head>`. May be it can fix your problem, but you will sacrifice IE9 features.

Comment: @alexi Yea it will probably work, but it doesnt matter in my case, since the customers are using ie7/8 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who runs in to this problem: The `XMLDocument` property doesn't exist in IE9, therefore causing the issue.